# Transfer of Songs/Playlists from PC to iPod

Tags: ipod-touch

How can I simply transfer songs/playlists (including non-iTunes songs) from my pc laptop to my iPod (purchased in June 2014)?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to just dump everything into iTunes and sync the iPod with it. Is there a particular reason you can't do that?

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be 'not possible'.
Any other consideration aside, how could it play a song that wasn't in iTunes in the first place?

You can drop m3u playlist files to iTunes, which will create new playlists in iTunes, but as far as I'm aware, the corresponding mp3 files must be present in the same folder for it to work.

iTunes, as far as an iPod is concerned, is the 'master' - so you would have to construct any new playlist in there & sync.

Comment: You can set your device to "manually managed" in which case the "always synced to 1 iTunes library" is not enforced any more.